# Criar várias sessões podem afetar a performance do usuário?

Tags: php, session

Meu site cria sessões com nome para cada página para serem usados em requisições e armazenam tokens únicos gerados a cada vez que a página é acessada e outros dados.

**Exemplo:**

```
$_SESSION['RSD']['page_username_id'] = ...
```

Porém se caso o usuário, abra uma nova guia do navegador com esta **mesma página**, a sessão é recriada com novos dados, sendo assim não é mais possível realizar requisições na mesma página anterior que ainda está aberta, pois o token da página foi alterado, ***e não quero isto!*** Gostaria que o usuário fosse livre pra acessar a mesma página em várias abas se preferir!

Pensei em gerar um nome único pra cada sessão assim que a página é carregada, porém isto criaria muitas, e muitas sessões.

Então gostaria de saber se criar várias sessões pode realmente afetar a performance do usuário, ou se tem outra solução na qual possa ter o mesmo resultado de criar algo que forneça o **token único** a cada vez q a página seja carregada e **não impeça** o usuário de abrir outras abas da mesma página, assim permitindo fazer requisições.

Comment: Se coloque na posição do usuário e veja se isso é bom. Eu, particularmente, não gosto, pq tira a liberdade do usuário. A não ser que seja algo estrito, que ele não possa abrir outra aba.

Comment: @Dvdsamm perdão, acho que me expressei mal, está acontecendo isto, e é justamente isto que quero resolver, como na pergunta pensei em adicionar mais caracteres únicos no fim do nome da sessão, para isto não acontece, porém acumularia muitas e muitas sessões até o usuário fechar o navegador. Atualizei a pergunta para ver se da mais sentido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você cria uma sessão no PHP, ele cria um cookie no navegador que é retornado para você em toda requisição. Esses dados de sessão não são enviados para o usuário, ele recebe um código e reencaminha para seu servidor em outras requisições.
Resumindo: Esses dados ficam em um arquivo físico no Servidor e não no browser do seu cliente.

Eu já trabalhei muito com sessão no php, porém tive problema quando atingia grandes números de usuários simultâneos. E quando fui ver, tinha que fazer balanceamento de carga. E nessa hora a sessão me atrapalhou bastante, então comecei a estudar sobre como controlar sessões e vi diversas maneira, e achei uma bem interessante e segura que uso atualmente, caso se interesse dê uma olhada no [JWT](https://jwt.io/).

Mas respondendo sua pergunta, pode impactar em um nível geral caso possua muitos acessos, e vai impactar a todos uma vez pois o gargalo fica no servidor. Com o JWT, você não teria esse tipo de problema.

Comment: Uma dúvida, é sobre aquela chave que é usada pra confirmar os dados do JWT, utilizar sempre apenas uma não é legal em questão de segurança, caso alguém descubra. Seria seguro eu criar uma senha a cada vez que o usuário fizer login e armazenar apenas no banco de dados?

Comment: @ViníciusLima o objetivo do JWT é ser um token que se auto gerencia, ou seja não seria legal consultar seu banco de dados a cada requisição só para ver se o token é válido (salvo casos onde é feito controle de sessão na aplicação). Você pode bolar um controle de como a chave funciona, exemplo. A cada uma hora você gera uma chave nova, e o intervalo do seu token é de 20 minutos. Então você poderia checar a chave atual, e caso o tempo do token não tenha expirado você faz a checagem utilizando a chave anterior. Assim você pode rotacionar a chave, e criar um algoritmo para que ela seja gerada.